# How to best save a value from a nested loop in a variable for further calculations

Tags: python

I have a nested loop function and want to return the last value to use it for further calculations. I dont want to use a list.append() method since each run of the loop only yields one value.
The code looks like this:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
 for record in event['Records']:
      if record['eventName'] == "INSERT" and "WW" in record["dynamodb"]["NewImage"]:
           details = record["dynamodb"]["NewImage"]
           for k,v in details.items():
                if k == 'WW':
                     for key in v:
                          print(v[key])
```

Now I want to store the value for v[key] in a variable to use for further calculations. How can this be done best?

Thank you in advance

A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question correctly, shouldn't you use a `generator`?
So substituting:

```py
yield v[key]
```

in lieu of

```
print(v[key])
```

That would allow to process the elements one by one. So, for the sake of the example, your could process elements like this:

```py
[your_func(this_value) for this_value in lambda_handler(your_event, your_context)
```